# ubuntu apertium package bug

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, compiler

I installed virtualbox 5.1.9 and kernel 4.4.0-21-generic/Ubuntu 16.04 then `apertium-vdi`

Installation went well but `apertium-preprocess-transfer` is giving me an error:

```
symbol lookup error: apertium-preprocess-transfer: undefined symbol: _ZN9XMLReader4readERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

I tried different ways and language pairs but it still gives the error.

What can I do?

Comment: How and/or from where did you install `apertium-vdi`? What's the output of `apt-cache policy libstdc++6`?

Comment: Is this apertium from the standard Ubuntu repos, or one of the projectjj ones in http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Ubuntu ? There have been similar reports where people switched between Release and Nightly apt repos.

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 3 years.